# Not able to find MVC option in new installed VS 2017 community

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have installed vs 2017 community edition, now that i want to create a new MVC application, when i click on file->new->project, there is no web option where i can select a MVC application.

[image]
did i miss something while installing vs community 2017? if yes then what changes can i make to see the mvc option

Comment: When you installed VS, did you enable the **ASP.NET and web development** option?

Comment: i guess i missed it, is there a way where i can do it now? or should i reinstall it all over again?

Comment: In your "Applications and features" (the name is different depending by your MS Windows version) search Visual Studio and "edit/change" your installation, check the missing "Web development" option

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to update your VS 2017 installation as described:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio

Ensure the `ASP.NET and web development` option is selected and then update.

Answer (score 10):

Please follow the below steps to open MVC project in visual studio 2017:


**Step 1**:Select the project as per below picture:
[image]

**Step 2**:select the MVC project

[image]

Comment: The web option is not there, so step 1 cannot be performed!

Answer (score 0):

- Open installer in administrator mode
- Select `Modify` option under workloads in `web & cloud`
- Select `ASP.NET and web development` option
- Look at right side of same window. There are selection options, please choose what you want to install then pick `Install while downloading` from drop down or `download all then install`
- Click the modify button.

Answer (score 0):

On my case, I used the ASP.NET Web Application(.Net Framework) unde Visual Basic

[image]